# Background in static page within dynamic blogger theme

Tags: html, css, background-color, blogger

Blog address: www..SailingDee.com
It uses a dynamic theme from blogger.
Redirect to a static page (www.sailingdee.com/p/welcometodee)
Blogger don't allow changing individual background colors to static pages.

Is there a way to change it within the HTML code accessible in the editor on Blogger? Static page has a HTML editor option although doesn't shows anything related to background colors.
Tried also CSS code but that only applies to the dynamic part of the blog.

The goal is to change the background color of the static page to match the (redish) color of the blog.

(this is the HTML in the static page)

```html
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://www.sailingdee.com/search/label/Blog"><img border="0" data-original-height="600" data-original-width="800" height="240" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-tMoena8-dQ4/Wq2xGaFLNKI/AAAAAAAADuo/Yj5IHK-KqIktxj9vqznUagLsIuHdcCppgCLcBGAs/s320/SailingDee_Blog_BlogBottom.png" width="320" /></a></div>
<br />
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/deethaifoodtruck"><img border="0" data-original-height="600" data-original-width="800" height="150" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-f86zx3r_Y_Y/Wq2xGgksptI/AAAAAAAADuw/v6AOadiTIrYRlBHJTy_NsXlyNrslMaWKwCLcBGAs/s200/DeeThaiFoodTruck_BlogBottom.png" width="200" /></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sailingdee"><img border="0" data-original-height="600" data-original-width="800" height="150" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-PM3T8_NpkL8/Wq2xGkm8unI/AAAAAAAADus/B5fITbfd4C4Qb2PG9pDz9NaBqw2H8X7fwCLcBGAs/s200/SailingDee_Facebook_BlogBottom.png" width="200" /></a></div>
<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you make your static page selfly , you can share your code so we solve your problems.

if you want to apply background color to whole your static page here is css

CSS:-

```
#header-container,ol.items,#attribution-container{
    background-color: white;
}
```

and if you want to apply background color to your inner page

CSS:-

```
.article,.viewitem-content,li.item{
    background-color: white;
}
```

you can choose your color.

Comment: Thks Rooter, the CSS only works for the dynamic pages...the static stays the same background color!

Comment: so give it ID and apply same code in it , if u satisfied give green arrow so my rep are increase

Comment: Thks. Thumbs up done! However I tried changing the code... ID...it just didn't change... Any ideas where and what code to insert there based on the HTML published?

Comment: First of all Id is unique so u can create one id in one tag and u can give more than one class to one tag.

Comment: First of all Id is unique so u can create one id in one tag and u can give more than one class to one tag.where you want to change, you can give class to it and if u cant do it give pen or fiddle of that so i can solve it.Thanks